# Gitlab ci Multiple trigger pipeline dynamic project name

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have a question about triggering a child pipeline.

In my case I generate multiple projects with each project having a different pipeline. On my main build pipeline I need to launch the child pipeline dynamically with the new project created by the same pipeline (so the project name is different each time).

My purpose here is to fill in the project with a dynamic path. It is working with a static one, but not with contain variables one that stay stuck in pending status.

**For example:**

Static one:

```
deploy:
  stage: init_project
  trigger:
    project: my/project
    branch: master
    strategy: depend
```

Dynamic one:

```
deploy:
  stage: init_project
  trigger:
    project: $my/$project
    branch: master
    strategy: depend
```

Is there is a solution or something wrong that I did here?

Comment: _stuck_ is the status of your pipeline. Was the downstream pipeline created at all? Or did the bridge job fail entirely? What is the status of the bridge job `deploy` ? Hover over it in the pipeline view. Where are you setting these variables?

Comment: thanks for you answer, the bridge job status is "pending" and when i click on it in the GUI view there is nothing. When i set the project with static value, the job is triggered and when i click on it, it redirect to the correct trigger pipeline in the new project. The variables are configured as pipeline env and i tried also to passed into the deploy but still the same.

Answer (score -1):

I did it by another way for people that want to do it.
It's some tricky thing but i did a template that rendered ci variable, and include it with an artifact for the trigger pipeline child. That job trigger the remote pipeline with the dynamic path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).